# Angular 7 project can't import node-vibrant

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to import `node-vibrant` into my Angular 7 project, and am running into some issues:

-I can import it using `import * as Vibrant from 'node-vibrant';`, but I get the following warning in VS Code:

`Module '"/Users/xxxx/Documents/dev/x/node_modules/node-vibrant/lib/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct`

The app live-reloads fine in development, but when I try to build it, the error above becomes fatal and it won't build.

-I can import it using `import * as Vibrant from 'node-vibrant';`, but I get the following warning (once again, it live-reloads fine in dev):
`Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.`

This error also becomes fatal when building.

I'm left being unable to build because there isn't any way I can import this file. Is there a decent workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Requiring vibrant within a method or function appears to work for me on Angular 7.

```
const vibrant = require('node-vibrant');
```

However, now this issue arises: https://github.com/akfish/node-vibrant/issues/85